# Saving a numpy homographic ndarray to file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array, save

I am trying to save a numpy ndarray homographic table to file (to use it later if needed) using:

```
h.tofile("h.h", sep=",", format="%s")
```

But when I later load it and try to use it on my calculations, using:

```
h = np.fromfile('h.h')
```

I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn + 1 == m.cols) in perspectiveTransform, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 2268
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...camera_to_point.py", line 166, in draw_circle2
    pointOut = cv2.perspectiveTransform(a, h)
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:2268: error: (-215) scn + 1 == m.cols in function perspectiveTransform
```

The interesting thing is that when I inspect the homographic matrix before saving to file and after retrieving it from file, I get:

Before saving:

```
h
array([[ 1.86326937e-02, -1.16700086e-02,  2.66963340e+00],
       [-7.51402803e-03, -3.88364336e-02,  1.69502899e+01],
       [-1.05249671e-03,  1.47791921e-02,  1.00000000e+00]])
[0:3] : [array([ 0.01863269, ...6696334 ]), array([-7.51402803e-...2899e+01]), array([-0.0010525 , ...        ])]
dtype: dtype('float64')
max: 16.950289865517334
min: -0.038836433627212195
shape: (3, 3)
size: 9
__internals__: {'T': array([[ 1.86326937e...000e+00]]), 'base': None, 'ctypes': <numpy.core._interna...ff8179b90>, 'data': <read-write buffer f...ff81797f0>, 'dtype': dtype('float64'), 'flags':   C_CONTIGUOUS : Tru...PY : False, 'flat': <numpy.flatiter obje...0x2f69850>, 'imag': array([[0., 0., 0.],... 0., 0.]]), 'itemsize': 8, 'nbytes': 72, 'ndim': 2, 'real': array([[ 1.86326937e...000e+00]]), 'shape': (3, 3), 'size': 9, ...}
```

After retrieving:

```
h
array([7.12605079e-67, 1.18069470e-95, 9.95130728e-43, 9.95309333e-43,
       5.40222957e-62, 4.32553942e-91, 2.74137239e-57, 3.06246782e-57,
       7.11172728e-38, 8.16641713e-43, 1.83288526e-76, 9.92883300e-96,
       1.69053846e-52, 9.34287548e-67, 9.05446937e-43, 7.11877246e-67])
[0:16] : [7.126050789796848e-67, 1.1806946993563433e-95, 9.951307279141174e-43, 9.95309332763986e-43, 5.402229572720159e-62, 4.325539416797926e-91, 2.741372385066056e-57, 3.0624678193742925e-57, 7.111727282221548e-38, 8.16641712557458e-43, 1.8328852622133153e-76, 9.928833002794128e-96, 1.690538456980108e-52, 9.342875479816443e-67, ...]
dtype: dtype('float64')
max: 7.111727282221548e-38
min: 9.928833002794128e-96
shape: (16,)
size: 16
__internals__: {'T': array([7.12605079e-6...7246e-67]), 'base': None, 'ctypes': <numpy.core._interna...ff8179790>, 'data': <read-write buffer f...ff8179470>, 'dtype': dtype('float64'), 'flags':   C_CONTIGUOUS : Tru...PY : False, 'flat': <numpy.flatiter obje...0x2f68e00>, 'imag': array([0., 0., 0., 0..., 0., 0.]), 'itemsize': 8, 'nbytes': 128, 'ndim': 1, 'real': array([7.12605079e-6...7246e-67]), 'shape': (16,), 'size': 16, ...}
```

Which shows two different matrices.

So, how can I save a numpy ndmatrix to a file and retrieve it successfully?

I am using opencv2 with python2.7

Comment: have you tried to pass the same arguments h = np.fromfile('h.h', sep=",", dtype="str") ?

Comment: Yes and the result (when tried to calculate points to the destination plane) was the one listed above as error.
Apparently for some reason, the h matrix gets distorted while saved to file. At least that is what I can verify after inspecting h, before and after getting saved to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `h.tofile("h.h", sep=",", format="%s")` a text file with all the numbers, separated by commas is stored, but the information of the dimension of the array is lost.
`h = np.fromfile('h.h')`  results in your output file. If you use
`h = np.fromfile('h.h', sep=",")` instead and then resize h like
`h.resize((3, 3))`
you would get the desired result.

If you use a binary file format, the array information can be retrieved.

np.arrays could be stored in binary file format using the pickle library:
script runs in python 2.7 and 3.8

```
from pickle import dump, load
from numpy import array

def save_h():

    h = array([[1.86326937e-02, -1.16700086e-02,  2.66963340e+00],
           [-7.51402803e-03, -3.88364336e-02,  1.69502899e+01],
           [-1.05249671e-03,  1.47791921e-02,  1.00000000e+00]])

    with open("save.h", "wb") as f:
        dump(h, f)
    with open("save.h", "rb") as f:
        h1 = load(f)
    return h, h1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stored, loaded = save_h()
    print(stored)
    print(loaded)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.86326937e-02 -1.16700086e-02  2.66963340e+00]
 [-7.51402803e-03 -3.88364336e-02  1.69502899e+01]
 [-1.05249671e-03  1.47791921e-02  1.00000000e+00]]
[[ 1.86326937e-02 -1.16700086e-02  2.66963340e+00]
 [-7.51402803e-03 -3.88364336e-02  1.69502899e+01]
 [-1.05249671e-03  1.47791921e-02  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
One question that comes to my mind is, why does python allow the use of a function for saving arrays (as clearly stated at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html which doesn't do the job?

Comment: In the Notes of your link is a hint: "This is a convenience function for quick storage of array data. Information on endianness and precision is lost...". With h.tofile("h.h", sep=",", format="%s") a text file with all the numbers, separated by commas is stored, but the information of the dimension of the array is lost.

Comment: But even the numbers are totally wrong. Not only the dimension. 
Anyhow, thanx again.

Comment: The numbers are wrong because  `sep=","` in your np.fromfile command is missing. The command probably separates the numbers " in ‘C’ order" (as stated in your posted link) and creates "new" numbers according to these separation rules. The first number might be a binary translation of a bracket. If you include  `sep=","`, then you get a one dimensional array with the right values which could be transferred into the original array using `h.resize((3, 3))` **(See top of my my edited answer)**.